# SSRS 2008 Time Format for a chart. does not work

Tags: reporting-services, time-format

I have an ssrs chat, I want to bind time valeus to y axis.

Data comes in "2013-11-21 16:07:31.000" format

I need 16:07 value as time. but no function give me that.

when I use cdate, and then Format it does not work . HHmm returns me an inteeger 1607 bur HH:mm doesnt work.

please help I am about to go crazy!

Comment: What does HH:mm do? And where are you applying it?

Comment: =Format(cdate(Fields!AverageTime.Value),"HH:mm") I am applying to y axis of an ssrs chart, it returns nothnig. but HHmm returns an int. for example 1743. but I need 17:43 as a time. I am trying to show an average time for each day of a week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try leaving your value, or setting up a calculated field that just uses `=CDate(Fields!AverageTime.Value)` or `=DateTime.Parse(Fields!AverageTime.Value)`

Then, I assume you use that date field as a category on your graph. Set the format on the X axis to HH:mm as shown below. Let the graph handle the display using format strings, don't use the `Format` function.

[image: Format X axis]